# What are the best strategies to use when you're invisible?

Tags: firetop-mountain

Invisibility gives a precious advantage at [Firetop Mountain](http://www.gamerz.net/~fm/Main/index.html), but it lasts only three turns and you need to quickly make the best use of it as it may give you a crucial advantage.
What are the best strategies or combos to use when you're invisible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A famous player (aka Nom) has written an essay (whose title is "What you can't see CAN hurt you") about this topic. You can read his point on Invisibility [here](http://www.gamerz.net/~fm/Tactics102_PPws.html).

Comment: Wow, what an awsome essay!!!